# Nginx is showing the default page instead of Django application (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx, gunicorn

I am trying to host django project with ubuntu, gunicorn and postgresql, also I use docker for development. As I don't have an IP-address for server I am just trying to host to standard django localhost in order to practise with Nginx (I used the guidline on DigitalOcean) as I am new to it. I've already tried a lot, but my problem persists.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11.1

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]


ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED=1

EXPOSE 8000

WORKDIR /cycle_proj

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN mkdir /cycle_proj/static && mkdir /cycle_proj/media

RUN apt update && apt -qy install gcc libjpeg-dev libxslt-dev \
    libpq-dev libmariadb-dev libmariadb-dev-compat gettext cron \
    openssh-client flake8 python3-venv python3-dev locales \
    postgresql postgresql-contrib nginx curl


COPY . .
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["gunicorn","-b","0.0.0.0:8001","core.wsgi:application"]
```

Here is docker-compose:

```
version: "3.9"


services:

  # Django
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/cycle_proj
      - static_volume:/cycle_proj/static
      - media_volume:/cycle_proj/media
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    env_file:
      - web.env
    image: cycle_proj
    container_name: django_cycle_api
    command: >
      bash -c "./manage.py collectstatic --noinput && ./manage.py migrate  && gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 core.wsgi:application"
    depends_on:
      - db


  # PostgreSQL
  db:
    image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - web.env
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data


  nginx:
    image: nginx
    depends_on:
      - web
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/cycle_proj/static
      - media_volume:/cycle_proj/media


volumes:
  db:
    driver: local

  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

Here is Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/web-for-cyclers;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=rroxxxsii
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/web-for-cyclers
ExecStart=/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/web-for-cyclers/venv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          core.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

gunicorn.socket:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

when i run `sudo nginx -t` I have this output:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

and when I access nginx page I get this output provided by docker container:

```
web-for-cyclers-nginx-1  | 172.18.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2023:01:37:15 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

I would be very grateful if someone finds the solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
> ```

unix domain sockets can't be used across containers.  Since you're already listening on TCP:

> ```
>         gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 core.wsgi:application
> ```

I recommend you change the `proxy_pass` to

```
proxy_pass http://web:8000;
```

Comment: So I need to start the service outside the docker just running this command
        `gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 core.wsgi:application`?

Comment: In the `web` container you already override the image's `command:` to run `gunicorn` as described here.  (It should probably be the default image `CMD`.)

Comment: "So I need to ... " No, you need to do what I suggested above.  Go back and read carefully.